# If/else condition is killing my function

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and I was trying to make a simple calculator for 2 values from input fields, plus an operator from a select drop down. 
Plus, a button that runs a function that writes the result of the operation. 
I have been building this, however, I am stuck in the stage of the con dition:
I want to: 
- if slect +, do a sum
- if select - do subtraction
- if select * do multiplication
- if select / do a division

Here is my function

```
function multiply() 
{
    var x = document.getElementById('x_value').value;
    var y = document.getElementById('y_value').value;
    var signal = get_operator();
    var u = parseInt(x,10) + parseInt(y,10);
    var v = x - y;
    var w = x * y;
    var z = x / y;

        /*
    if(signal == plus)
        {
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = u;
        }

    else if(signal == minus)
        {
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = v;
        }

    else if(signal == times)
        {
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = w;
        }

    else 
        {
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = z;
        }

        */

}
```

Note that I have commented the logical test on purpose.
The get_operator function is working well

```
function get_operator(operator) 
{
    var operator = document.getElementById("operation").value;
    return operator;
}
```

and the print result button itself is working. 
If I put for example

```
function multiply() 
{
    var x = document.getElementById('x_value').value;
    var y = document.getElementById('y_value').value;
    var signal = get_operator();
    var u = parseInt(x,10) + parseInt(y,10);
    var v = x - y;
    var w = x * y;
    var z = x / y;

    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = u /*[or any other of my values]*/;

}
```

so, the issue is clearly with the if/else condition test. Because, when I use it, the button stops working.

Could you please be so kind as to give me some hint?
Thank you in advance

Comment: The values `times` etc — are they variables? How are they defined?

Comment: @Manngo Or are they strings without quotes?  I have to know!

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the strings into numbers for all operations, not only additions:

```
x = parseInt(x, 10);
y = parseInt(y, 10);
```

You need to compare your operator to a string value:

```
if (signal == 'plus') { ... }
else if (signal == 'minus') { ... }
else ...
```

The fixed code then looks like:

```js
function get_operator(operator) {
  var operator = document.getElementById("operation").value;
  return operator;
}

function multiply() {
  var x = document.getElementById('x_value').value;
  var y = document.getElementById('y_value').value;
  var signal = get_operator();

  x = parseInt(x, 10);
  y = parseInt(y, 10);

  var u = x + y;
  var v = x - y;
  var w = x * y;
  var z = x / y;
  var z = x / y;

  if (signal == 'plus') {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = u;
  } else if (signal == 'minus') {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = v;
  } else if (signal == 'times') {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = w;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = z;
  }

}

document.getElementById("compute").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  multiply();
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="x_value">
<input type="text" id="y_value">
<select id="operation">
  <option value="plus">+</option>
  <option value="minus">-</option>
  <option value="times">*</option>
  <option value="divide">/</option>
</select>
<button id="compute">Compute</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

A much cleaner way to implement the same functionality is given by:

```js
const operations = {
  "plus": (a, b) => a + b,
  "minus": (a, b) => a - b,
  "times": (a, b) => a * b,
  "divide": (a, b) => a / b,
}

const compute  = document.getElementById("compute");
const operator = document.getElementById("operator");
const first    = document.getElementById("first-operand");
const second   = document.getElementById("second-operand");
const result   = document.getElementById("result");

compute.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const operation = operations[operator.value];
  result.textContent = operation(first.valueAsNumber, second.valueAsNumber);
});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="first-operand">
<input type="number" id="second-operand">
<select id="operator">
  <option value="plus">+</option>
  <option value="minus">-</option>
  <option value="times">*</option>
  <option value="divide">/</option>
</select>
<button id="compute">Compute</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Nice refactor :)